# SQL - Visual Studio - fill table if related data is empty

Tags: sql, database, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

In my data source "Properties" is linked to "tenants" and I want to fill a table using a SQL query where tenant does not exist for that property. 
In other words, "where that property is vacant."

What is the SQL statement for something like this?

```
SELECT tblProperties.Type, tblProperties.PropertyID, tblProperties.Street, tblProperties.Unit, tblProperties.City, tblProperties.State, tblProperties.Zip, tblProperties.Description, tblTenant.TenantID
FROM dbo.tblProperties
JOIN tblTenant 
ON tblProperties.PropertyID = tblTenant.PropertyID
WHERE tblTenant.TenantID = ''
```

Comment: Can you post some code please, so we can get a better idea of what your exact issue is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Properties and Tenants are both tables in your database?

Are they joined by a cross-reference table or...?  It would be helpful to see the table structures.

Assuming that's the case, you just want something like:

```
SELECT * FROM Properties 
WHERE PropertyId NOT IN 
   (SELECT PropertyId FROM PropertyTenants)
```

Comment: I appreciate you're trying to help without any schema or code from the OP, but your query (in addition to being syntactically incorrect - select... *from* rather than *in* in the subquery) doesn't take account of whether there is a tenant *now* vs whether there have *ever* been tenants in a property.

Comment: Oh very true, select propertyId -from- propertyTenants :)

And yes, I don't know if the cross-ref table has historical data, and if so, how to query it.  Presumably the OP does.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this: 
    SELECT Property.PropertyID, Property.TenantID
    FROM Property LEFT JOIN Tenant ON Property.[TenantID] = Tenant.[TenantID]
    WHERE (((Tenant.TenantID) Is Null));

This should show what properties don't have Tenants,  Suggest you first try it with JUST the id fields, then add in the other fields later to keep the query simple and help with troubleshooting.  If you have the potential to have multiple tenants who have offices in more than one property, this is a many-to-many relationship that is best documented in an index table.